# Unknown provider: i18nFilterProvider <- i18nFilter

Tags: angularjs, migration

I've migrated my angular application from Angular 1.3.15 to Angular 1.5.5. I'm struggling with this for about a day and tried various possible solutions mentioned in the [AngularJS Error Reference](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=i18nFilterProvider%20%3C-%20i18nFilter), checked my code to not contain,

- Multiple module definitions for the same moudule
- Not contain a controller inside another controller.
- Attempting to inject a scope object into anything that's not a controller or a directive.
- Also tried checking the dependency issue

Couldn't find any fruitful solution to this, the whole screen seems like broken, like, angular itself hasn't been loaded, things, like interpolations are not resolved to their values.

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: To answer this question i think some code is required. Can you post in your question both the code where you initialize your main module and eventually where you use a filter called i18n? because it looks like somewhere in your application you are trying to use a filter called i18nFilter which is not injected in your application

Answer (score 0):

The i18nFilter which you are referencing in your application is likely being provided via the [angular-localization](https://github.com/doshprompt/angular-localization#i18n-filter) library.

There are a number of issues raised in the project relating to version compatibility when upgrading the AngularJS version.

I suggest you track down the version you are referencing and upgrade to a supported version for AngularJS 1.5.5